# Get line breaks in the my-sql_fetch_array table results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html-table

I have a simple project that I am working on and I'm having a hard time finding the code I need to get line breaks in the following table:

---

```
<?php 

// connect to the database

$host = '###';
$username = '###';
$pass = '####';

mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("####") or die(mysql_error());

// select everything from the table

$query = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";

while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
{
    echo "<td>".$row['employeeid']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['firstname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['department']."</td>";

}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

// disconnect from the database

mysql_close();
```

?>

---

Everything works correctly and it grabs data from the correct database and table. But when it displays results it is all on the same line ("record1record2record3") and I'd like a line break between employee records.

I've searched this question and it seems like my results all show me an entirely different way of doing this. I've already got the code written and fussed with it a lot to get it working. Can I just make a simple alteration to the above code to get the breaks I want?

Answer (score 0):

The `<tr>` tags must also be inside the while loop so that they are outputted for each row. They make the rows in the HTML table.

```
while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
{
     echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['employeeid']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['firstname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['department']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick help. When I insert those two tags it gives me a syntax error on line 45 (the echo <tr> tags after this loop. Does this page need more editing that your original answer?

Comment: Please always show more information about the error, update your question. I think that you have a weird character in some place when you copy and paste.

Comment: I reverted to an earlier version of the code, and the wrote the additional tags exactly as above and it worked fine. I am not sure why it failed originally, but I'm sure it was a weird character in there somewhere on my end.

Comment: Also wanted to add that I do appreciate the patience with an obvious new user. I'm still learning the system here and don't want to be too annoying to all you experienced users. So thanks again for that. I'll be adding points for your responses as soon as my reputation allows. :)